# What is the difference between normal docker image and s2i image?

Tags: docker, s2i

I tried running a [centos:centos7](https://hub.docker.com/_/centos) docker image in interactive mode it worked fine and container started successfully, but when I try running [centos/python-36-centos7:latest](https://hub.docker.com/r/centos/python-36-centos7) , the below text was shown instead of container.

```
This is a S2I python-3.6 centos base image:
To use it, install S2I: https://github.com/openshift/source-to-image
Sample invocation:
s2i build https://github.com/sclorg/s2i-python-container.git --context-dir=3.6/test/setup-test-app/ centos/python-36-centos7 python-sample-app
You can then run the resulting image via: podman run -p 8080:8080 python-sample-app
```

Refer the attached screenshot
[image: Image screenshot]

What is the difference between these two images?

Comment: The README at https://github.com/openshift/source-to-image explains everything nicely.